# SQL - Why is my percentage aggregation blank?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to get **percentage** of issues that are marked as **closed**, for some reason it's coming out as 0 for all entries.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(IF(progress = 'CLOSED', id)) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1.0 * (COUNT(IF(progress = 'CLOSED', id)) / COUNT())
    END as pct_closed,
    assigned_date
FROM table
WHERE assigned_date >= YYYY-MM-DD
GROUP BY 2
```

Comment: The `where` goes before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it now. This was only in the question and not in my actual query so the question still stands :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN progress = 'CLOSED' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as closed_ratio,
       assigned_date
FROM table
WHERE assigned_date >= ?  -- date format should be YYYY-MM-DD
GROUP BY assigned_date;
```

Comment: Ah! Wonderful, and of course! Thanks again for your help. I've gone ahead and updated the date format in the question too